# gnuplot get "warning: Number of pixels cannot be factored into integers matching grid." when scale the axis

Tags: plot, gnuplot, scale

When I use splot in gnuplot,and scale a axis, I got a warning message"warning: Number of pixels cannot be factored into integers matching grid."

The data is like

```
5539 07/10/2019 13:13:48.265 3.324788E+0 2.488200E+0 2.177561E+0 2.945671E+0 -42.143070E-3   -1.151566E+0    35  21  0
5540 07/10/2019 13:13:48.265 3.315912E+0 2.479325E+0 2.163098E+0 2.913973E+0 -73.840880E-3   -1.203222E+0    36  21  0
5541 07/10/2019 13:13:48.265 3.322815E+0 2.489515E+0 2.179205E+0 2.938627E+0 -37.447099E-3   -1.145696E+0    37  21  0
5542 07/10/2019 13:13:48.265 3.318213E+0 2.480968E+0 2.162440E+0 2.922191E+0 -67.970915E-3   -1.205570E+0    38  21  0
5543 07/10/2019 13:13:48.265 3.347141E+0 2.507594E+0 2.177890E+0 3.025502E+0 27.122514E-3    -1.150392E+0    39  21  0
5544 07/10/2019 13:13:48.265 3.335307E+0 2.515155E+0 2.165728E+0 2.983238E+0 54.124353E-3    -1.193830E+0    40  21  0
5545 07/10/2019 13:13:48.265 3.336950E+0 2.508580E+0 2.162440E+0 2.989108E+0 30.644493E-3    -1.205570E+0    41  21  0
```

When I use

```
splot "QuadFeildData.Jul.10.2019_13.13.txt" u 9:($10*3+3):($8*10) w image
```

Everything looks fine.THe figure looks like:
[image]

Once I tried to

```
splot "QuadFeildData.Jul.10.2019_13.13.txt" u ($9):($10*3+3):($8*10) w image
```

where the column 9 is scaled.
THe error message pop out 
warning: Number of pixels cannot be factored into integers matching grid. N = 5545  K = 3
And no figure plot out.

How could I figure it out? I have to scale all axis.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that error message comes from a bug in gnuplot version 4. The method of handling image data was changed in version 5 and that particular bug is no longer triggered.

Comment: I am using 5.2 .

Comment: Are you sure? That error message does not exist anywhere in the source code for 5.2

Comment: Some git archaeology: that error message and the bug it reported were removed in May 2015. The fix first appeared in released version 5.0 Patchlevel 3 (Feb 2016).

Comment: G N U P L O T
 Version 5.2 patchlevel 4    last modified 2018-06-01

 Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2018
 Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

Comment: That is worrisome, but I cannot explain it.  I stand by the statement that the error message you report is no longer anywhere in the gnuplot source code, and it has not been since the release of version 5.0 (patchlevel 3).   Please file a bug report at https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/ with full information about your OS, you version of gnuplot, and where you obtained it. It would be valuable to the development team to learn how/where a mislabeled gnuplot executable is reaching users. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I will.